# How to download an archive and extract it without saving the archive to disk using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I was trying to download a zip file using Invoke-WebRequest and feed it to Extract-Archive on the fly. I am not 100% keen on not using disk in the process (it would be nice though), but if a temp file manifests, it would be nice if it went away after the process. I was trying this command (and several similar):

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.0.0-beta.8/PowerShell-6.0.0-beta.8-win-x64.zip | Extract-Archive -DestinationPath C:\Kellekek\Microsoft\PowerShell\6.0.0-beta.8
```

but it simply hangs after the download finishes. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in PS Core?

Comment: I dont feel you can use pipe line to do this. Why do you want to avoid saving it to local hard disk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. `Invoke-WebRequest` returns an object of the type `WebResponseObject`. This object has the following properties:

```
$x |get-member

   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebResponseObject

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
Equals            Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode       Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType           Method     type GetType()
ToString          Method     string ToString()
BaseResponse      Property   System.Net.WebResponse BaseResponse {get;set;}
Content           Property   byte[] Content {get;set;}
Headers           Property   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,string] Headers {get;}
RawContent        Property   string RawContent {get;set;}
RawContentLength  Property   long RawContentLength {get;}
RawContentStream  Property   System.IO.MemoryStream RawContentStream {get;}
StatusCode        Property   int StatusCode {get;}
StatusDescription Property   string StatusDescription {get;}
```

`Content` sounds promising. You could try to use this with `Extract-Archive`, I can't try it because my PowerShell doesn't know this cmdlet and I don't know where you got it.

That would be:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest https://your/url/...).Content | Extract-Archive -DestinationPath C:\Kellekek\Microsoft\PowerShell\6.0.0-beta.8
```

If that doesn't work you can use a temporary file, like this:

```
# Create a new temporary file
$tmp = New-TemporaryFile
# Store the download into the temporary file
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile $tmp https:/.....
# extract the temporary file (again, this is untested)
$tmp | Extract-Archive
# remove temporary file
$tmp | Remove-Item
```

Comment: use Expand-Archive instead

Comment: And you know that `Expand-Archive` is the same as `Extract-Archive`?

Comment: you are correct.may be different. it was not found in any powershell version.. "Extract-Archive"....and also  $tmp = New-TemporaryFile creates a file with .tmp extension .. not a .zip

Comment: Terribly sorry, indeed, it is `Expand-Archive`. I use an alias to it `ear` and forgot the verb is expand, not extract. Other than that, it very much seems that Expand-Archive is only able to extract files from disk. It cannot take the input as the array of bytes from Content, nor as a string from RawContent, or as the RawContentStream.

Comment: Given the constraints, I'll accept this as an answer and I'll wrap the 4 liner into an `Expand-WebArchive` cmdlet.

Comment: Please note that if using the `New-TemporaryFile` approach, you will need to `Rename-Item` it to a .zip extension, use that as the `-OutFile` of `Invoke-WebRequest`, and then clean up the correct path at then end. I did not have any luck with piping the `.Content` to `Expand-Archive`.

Answer (score 3):

Had to adjust Geralds answer to make it work:

```
# create temp with zip extension (or Expand will complain)
$tmp = New-TemporaryFile | Rename-Item -NewName { $_ -replace 'tmp$', 'zip' } –PassThru
#download
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile $tmp $url
#exract to same folder 
$tmp | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath $PSScriptRoot -Force
# remove temporary file
$tmp | Remove-Item
```